# Creating indicies in Neo4j, on an non-existent schema?

Tags: c#, neo4j, cypher

I've just started using Neo4j. Basically I'm just connecting to Neo4j, using neo4jclient, storing several millions of POCO objects. Everything seems to be working fine. Almost.

When inserting several 100.000 nodes with the same label, merging on an unique attribute, performance drops significantly. Hence, I'm considering creating an index. Without an index, I'm experiencing timeouts in the HTTP layer, but with an index everything works fine. That is, I'm seeing exceptions like "connection closed" with Neo4j consuming 100% of availble CPU.

**The real question is:** - How do I create an index up front, in a blank database, before storing anything? Do I have to define a schema, and how do I do that? I know I can create indices using e.g. "CREATE INDEX ON :Person(name)". Will that work if there aren't any Person nodes in the database? I've tried, but when I check the `:schema` there are no indices defined.

I've checked [online resources](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher-examples) but am not able to find an answer.

---

**Update:** I've successfully created indicies (on an empty database), using the following code. Basically I have an abstract base class defining a `TypeName` property (used as `Label`) and a `KeyPropertyName` (to merge on).

```
private void CreateIndices()
{
    var exporters = typeof(NodeBase)
        .Assembly.GetTypes()
        .Where(t => t.IsSubclassOf(typeof(NodeBase)) && !t.IsAbstract)
        .Select(t => (NodeBase) Activator.CreateInstance(t));

    foreach (var exporter in exporters)
    {
        this.client.Cypher.Create(string.Format("CONSTRAINT ON (n:{0}) ASSERT n.{1} IS UNIQUE", exporter.TypeName, exporter.KeyPropertyName)).ExecuteWithoutResults();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure creating indices and unique constraints on an empty neo4j database works just fine and it is recommended to have those before inserting your data.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try tomorrow and get back to you. I have some code, that creates unique constraints using reflection. I'll modify it to create indices. A unique constraint might not be implemented using an index in Neo4j?

Comment: if you have already an index, you'll need to drop it first for creating the constraint

Comment: If I create an unique constraint, do I still need to create an index (on the same attribute) for performance reasons?

Comment: Not at all, it is implictly created for you